# Не получается установить пакет разработчика .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Я не являюсь .NET разработчиком и с данной технологией не связан, но ради интереса решил посмотреть как создаются модификации для игры My Summer Car, которая разработана на движке Unity.

Возможно, я не прав, но .NET Framework 3.5 у меня установлен:
["Скрин включение отключение компонентов Windows"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5tk0.png)
В "отдельных компонентах" Visual Studio 2022 Installer отображаются "Средства разработки для .NET Framework 3.5", они также установлены.

Но при попытке сборки проекта высвечивается ошибка:

`не найдены ссылочные сборки для .NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Full v3.5. Чтобы устранить эту проблему, установите пакет разработчика (пакет SDK или пакет нацеливания) для этой версии платформы или перенацельте приложение. Пакеты разработчика для платформы .NET Framework можно скачать на странице https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks.`

Пытался решить проблему самостоятельно, но не смог. Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: 3.5 устарел лет 12 назад, вы для чего-то очень старого пытаетесь его прикрутить? Для Unity насколько мне известно библиотеки под .NET Standard пишутся, версия зависит от версии движка. А вообще фреймворк 3.5 входит в комплект установки фреймворка 4.8 или 4.8.1, он обычно предустановлен в системе. Отдельно 3.5 устанавливать не требуется. Если я что-то путаю и речь про SDK, то ее можно установить через установщик Visual Studio Community. Вам же нужна IDE для разработки. Собираете чем и как?